# Technologies needed for developing Android apps with Rich Graphics

Tags: android, android-layout

A newbie question.
I am a newcomer to Java/Android (even UI development) .
My test apps look a little drab even though they do what the intend to do (with respect to app functionality).
Apart from Java, what are other technology needed for graphic rich app (oval 3d buttons etc).

PS: I did a lil research on this before coming here and found most of the questions were asked with respect to game development.But I am not interested in game development though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my history of making nice looking apps it usually all comes down to positioning the buttons and other things nicely and making custom images for buttons. If you want to simplify some things try using [LIBGDX's](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) UI tools. They allow a somewhat simplified way to load in custom images and scale/position them according to screen size.

Comment: again libgdx has its core written on android... so for ui stuffs i don't feel the need of libgdx, as libgdx is meant for full fledged games is what i feel (as i have games written in LIBGDX)...

Comment: As x-code said it comes down to making nice pictures and using them as buttons.